# Question on names in ancient Rome

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome

I'm writing a novel set in 268 AD and the character is called Marcus Piavonius Victorinus, one of the many upstart military emperors during the Crisis of the Third Century. I've heard that by this time, praenomens were out of use. So what would the character's mother have called him if not Marcus?

Comment: Where did you hear that they 'were out of use'? Isn't it rather that they were [not recorded in public records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenomen)?

Comment: Since Marcus *is* a praenomen, then ipso facto your character has a praenomen and would be called that by his close family.

Comment: Praenomens were out of use amongst women (had been for centuries) who typically used the feminine form of their family name. So in your example all females born into the household would be called Piavonia. Male praenomens might be reduced to an initial so M. Piavonius Victorinus.

Comment: @Daniel that looks like an answer. Please write one.

Comment: Can you please let us know when/where the novel is available? Or if you need proofreaders? Such novels consume an unhealthy portion of my day, and I wish to increase said portion.  Thanks